# Does mnesia handle paging?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a relatively large dataset (20GB) that I want to cache locally, but the machines it is running on only has about 8GB of RAM. Does mnesia in disc_copies mode support paging, or does the entire dataset have to fit in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mnesia disc_copies do get read entirely into memory. See http://erlang.org/faq/mnesia.html section 11.5. The files are also limited to 2GB unless you fragment the table.

Comment: Only `disk_only_copies` have the 2 GB limit (because they use DETS files as backing storage, which use 31 bit references internally - and in practice you do not want to be anywhere near the 2GB limit, because if you hit it, you will get silent data corruption, so you should probably stay under 1.5 GB). `disc_copies` tables are stored as disk logs, and do not have any such size limit, but large tables take a lot of time to read into memory at startup.